# Getting Articles category laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get category name of articles. This is my CategoriesController:

```
public function show(Category $category)
{          
    $articles = $category->articles()->latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('categories.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

When I try to do it like this: `{{$articles->category()}}`

I'm getting this error: `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection' does not have a method 'category'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the category getting passed to your controller action, so just pass that instance to your view rather than trying to grab it from every article item and potentially adding more database queries to your controller action.

```
public function show(Category $category)
{
    return view('categories.index', compact('articles', 'category'));
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It's working! `{{$category->name}}` and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

`$articles` would, in this case, be a collection of several articles. Therefore you can't simply do `{{ $articles->category }}`.

This should work, however:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
  {{ $article->category }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm getting this now:
`[{"id":4,"slug":"naujienos","name":"Naujienos","created_at":"2015-07-09 10:23:07","updated_at":"2015-07-09 10:23:07","pivot":{"article_id":2,"category_id":4}}]` but wtihout errors just this plain text in page.

Comment: If you want the category name, then: `{{ $article->category->name }}`. But as has already been mentioned, this results in a lot of queries, unless you [eager-load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) table relations.